# MicroPython on STM32F746 controller

Tags: arm, micropython, stm32f7, st-link

I have a PCB which contain an **STM32F746** controller , I want to run micropython on that controller for that reason I have compiled the code of STM32F7 DISC board from that repository (https://github.com/micropython/micropython.git) and than I have upload it to the controller using the ST_Link ,I have got this errors :
14:21:59 : The elf loader Program function fails.
14:22:01 : The elf loader Program function fails.                                          14:22:01 : Memory-Loader error
14:22:01 : Error occured during program operation!
14:22:01 : Programming error @ 0x08000000!
14:22:09 : Programming error @ 0x08020000!

I thought maybe there is a problem with the linker file but i didn´t know how to fix it .
Any help ,Please !

Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it , the problem was with the version of the STLink , I couldn´t even erase the chip and , I just download the latest version and the firmware is uppload it correctly .

I am stuck with an other error , I am working on the stm32f746 controller which is embedded inside a pcb , after uploading the firmware of the f7Disc to my controller nothing happen and I could´t get the python interpreter , I thought the firmware doesn´t work because my computer doesn´t detect a virtual com port .
Any help , Please !!!!